# QueryBuilder in the BuildForm

Tags: forms, symfony, symfony-2.6

I have An entity Equipe that have OneToMany relation with entity Employe. It means that a team have many employees. So in EquipeType I tried to show list of employees and a chekckbox infront each of them if I want to add an employee in that team I only have to check it. That works but my problem is how to show the name, id and all other properties and put them in table. I need a for statement but what to put in it? thanks [this is how I get it in my twig](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DDa2I.png)

My FormBuilder

```
->add('date')
        ->add('nom')
        ->add('employes', 'entity', array(
            'class' => 'OCUserBundle:Employe',
            'property' => 'username',
            'multiple' => true,
            'expanded' => true,
            'query_builder' => function (EntityRepository $er) {
                return $er->createQueryBuilder('u')
                    ->orderBy('u.id', 'ASC');
            },
```

My twig

```
{{form_widget(form.employes)}}
```

Comment: what Symfony2 version do you use?

Comment: I'm using Symfony 2.6

Answer (score 0):

Since Symfony 2.7 `property` in options is changed to `choice_label` and could be a callback like this

```
'choice_label' => function ($employee) {
    return $employee->getName().'/'.$employee->getId();
}
```

This is explained in the [EntityType field documentation](http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/entity.html)

If you use Symfony earlier than the 2.7 version you should declare a method in Employee, something like this:

```
public function getDisplayName()
{ 
    return $this->getName().'/'.$this->getId(); 
}
```

and then in options declare property as

```
'property' => 'display_name'
```

See the [EntityType field documentation for Symfony 2.6](http://symfony.com/doc/2.6/reference/forms/types/entity.html#property) for more information.